# increment operator not working in python code

Tags: python

Increment operator issue in python code :

In following code :

```
n = eval(input ("enter the rows for pattern"))
temp =1
for i in range(1,n+1) :
    temp =1
    while temp <=i :
        print("*", end = '')
        temp++
    print('')
```

The output is:

```
> File  "C:\user\new\pattern.py" , line 7
>     temp++  <p>       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax </p>
```

also if I convert `temp++` to `++temp` 
it is running in infinite loop

Can someone explain me what's wrong in it?

Edit 1 : AS increment operator don't work in python, so why ++temp is giving an infinte loop?

Comment: Use `temp += 1`. Python doesn't have `++`

Comment: There is no increment op in python. temp += 1. Do this.

Comment: Python doesn't have any increment operator

Comment: BTW, don't use `eval` if a simple `int` does the trick. In fact, never ever use `eval`: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: will remember for next time about Eval  :)

Comment: @Chris : why ++temp was working ?

Comment: @LuciFiEr `++temp` is equivalent as just doing `1` since positive of positive of `1` is `1` :). Thus effectively doing nothing, and never breaking the `while` loop, thus to infinity and beyond!

Comment: gotcha ,new to this will take some time to rectify silly mistakes :)